# Hyperledger: 'membersrvc' not Responding

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

My Development Environment has already started after all the pre-requisites needed:

`vagrant up
vagrant ssh
make membersrvc
make peer`

But when trying to Start the **membersrvc** by doing `membersrvc` after coming into the folder `$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric`, It is not Responding!

No Response even after One Hour!
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should start membersrvc at first in another terminal window. Only when membersvc started, the peer process will be able to get valid certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how `membersrvc` supposed to behave. when you execute `membersrvc` command you don't see any output whatsoever, however you can verify that it is running by opening a separate terminal window and running

```
ps -a | grep membersrvc
```

command.

Besides, as **Sergey Balashevich** commented, you also need to make sure that `membersrvc` is started and running before`peer` process will be able to get a valid certificate, which means that you need to start both `membersrvc` and `peer` process in separate terminal windows simultaneously.

If you want to run all the processes in a single terminal window you can execute them in background as`membersrvc > result 2>&1 &` it will start the process and redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to a `result` file which you can specify. If you don't care about the output at all - you can use `/dev/null` instead of specifying the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That Helped!! :)